# Is std::vector::size() slower than keeping track of size manually?

Tags: c++, vector

Does `std::vector::size()` recompute the size of the vector each time it's called, or does it maintain a counter that is only modified when the vector is modified?  For example, if I have class with a `std::vector<double>` member, would there be any speed benefit to keeping track of its size in a separate counter?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source? Its implementation-dependent anyway.

Comment: While agreeing with @littleadv, it would be a strange implementation that did not keep a private count field.

Comment: I disagree with whoever voted to close for "not a real question". It's rather clear what is being asked.

Comment: While it's not inconceivable that a separate member might be faster, it's a sure-fire way to introduce bugs, as you now need to keep two things in sync at all times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`size()` is guaranteed to have constant time complexity, and in any sane implementation will be as fast an operation as you can possibly have.

Comment: What could be the reasons, then, that for many of my programs, when I'm profiling it (using gprof) std::vector::size() is usually an outstanding time waster? Calling size() in a "for loop" is never a good idea.

Comment: Simply put using A.size() multiple times vs cache A.size in variable then using that variable those many times, has any performance difference ?

Answer (score 3):

```
this->_Mylast - this->_myFirst
```

typically involves two memory fetches.  If you maintain the count in a register, it *might* just be faster.  I say *might*, because in a small loop, the two values being subtracted are going to be in cache, which is not always a whole lot slower than registers - depends on the machine.  And a clever compiler, working with a tight loop, could maintain both in registers anyhow, if it's getting its data flow analysis right.  In a not-so-small loop, you'll never notice the difference.  Maintaining it in a register means an extra operation per iteration to update the register, which might be free if it can be done in parallel with other operations, or it might cost an instruction cycle.  So it'll be tough to measure a difference.

At any rate, your mileage **will** vary according to processor, even if every implementation of the STL has the same code for `size()` in it.

Answer (score 2):

It's no need to keeping track of its size in a separate counter, because it's done inside vector. The code on this function is like this:

```
iterator begin() {return start;}
iterator end() {return finish;}
size_type size() const { return size_type(end() - begin());}

iterator start;
iterator finish;
```

The variable “start”、“finish” will be changed once you push or pop elements, so function size() only need time of minus. If use a separate counter, you'll also have one plus or minus  when you push or pop elements.

Answer (score 1):

No - just use `std::vector::size()`

On MSVC, it's implemented as `this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst` - you can't beat that.

Comment: "*On MSVC, it's implemented as `this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst` - you can't beat that.*" Sure you can (if you don't mind the memory overhead): `this->_Mysize`.

Comment: I guess as always, it depends.  If the way the vector is used results in frequent size modifications, keeping size as a member variable will be less efficient overall.  If the size changes infrequently, calculating the difference between first and last will be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, it hardly can get faster. Only in cases your vector size is constant, you could indeed save some cpu cycles by using this very fact. Actually, then you can skip querying the size altogether. This might be important for a ridiculously often repeated iterations in a rendering loop etc. Just imagine the difference between:

```
// reset vector of size=3 to value 10

for( size_t i=0; i < myvec.size(); ++i )
{
   myvec[i] = 10.0;
}
```

versus

```
 myvec[0] = myvec[1] = myvec[2] = 10.0;
```

A typical use case is a 3d coordinate vector, an ip-address etc. But be ready to replace some std::vector routines that query size() internally, with your own. So the gist is, to save cpu cycles, the size operator is not a target, look for other logical places. When your vector does not change its size, even temporarily, you have a foot in the door to squeeze some cpu cycles out.

PS: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend to tell where to optimize first. And indeed, the size operator pops up quite often as the top candidate; at least for some algorithms.

Good Luck!